# Vue custom component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my SPA I have a `v-card` with a `v-card-title`.

`v-card-text` is compound of many other component / text and a close button with a lot of logic and properties.

Is there a way to create a custom component (something like `my-card-text`) which automatically includes the commond part and the button which are always the same?

I'd like to write something like:

```
<v-card>
   <my-card-text>
      <something/>
      <a>a link</a>
      <v-btn>OK</v-btn>
   </my-card-text>
</v-card>
```

Is it possible to write code in custom component?

Comment: Try it SLOT  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: yes, slots, try vuetify slots https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-card/#slots

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible. You can use slots for the contents that need to be passed along. If you want custom behavior (on a click for example), you can also emit events using $emit to the parent component.